# Rails-tutorial: cloud9 server not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, cloud9

I am going through  the rails tutorial. I am on chapter 1, section 1.3.2.
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-the_hello_application

After I ran the command

> rails server -b $IP -p $PORT

I see the following:

> => Booting Puma
>
> => Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
>
> => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>
> Puma starting in single mode...
>
> - Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
> - Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
> - Environment: development
> - Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080
>
> Use Ctrl-C to stop

The terminal says it is running on http://0.0.0.0:8080, but when I visit this URL I get the follow error:

> ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

I am completely new to Rails. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to access the project through the IP address and port number rails returns to you--it won't work!

Try `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`

For further clarification check this [link](https://community.c9.io/t/running-a-rails-app/1615)

The app will be running on  http://[your_workspacename]-[your_username].c9users.io

Comment: Thanks but that is the command I used. I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: http://0.0.0.0:8080 is not the ip. It's something in the line of  http://workspacename-username.c9users.io

Comment: Ohh yeah!! I got it! Thanks.